# Behavior for dragging multiple mail items in OSX is different than dragging single.

Tags: macos, email, finder

I'm using OSX, and I have an email in the inbox, and a Finder folder nearby. 
[image]

If I drag the email into the window I get a nice file in the folder with the subject I'd expect and so on. [image]
dragging....
[image]
and now in the file.

My problem is this, if I select more than one mail message in mail, I'd like all the mail messages to be put in the folder - but unfortunatley, I get a red mark and the action is proibited.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You're probably doing nothing wrong, but Apple failed to implement this.

Comment: The "red mark" is a *2*, for two selected emails. Other than that, I agree with slhck.

Comment: Migrating to Apple.SE because Joe asked.

Answer (score 1):

As some users have commented, there just isn't an implementation in the Apple Mail application to do this, for some reason. An alternative is to make a new mailbox in Mail (Menu -> Mailbox -> New), copying/moving the emails over there and right clicking on the mailbox, choosing Export. This will make a mbox-file with the emails that can be opened with most email applications.

You can also mark all the emails you want to save, choose Save As from the File menu, and save them. This will save them as a single rtf-file.

It's strange that Apple hasn't implemented this, they definitely should. I looked into an Automator-solution as well, but the mail-actions are very limited, unfortunately.